# Does C# support a variable number of arguments, and how?

Tags: c#, .net, variables, arguments, parameters

Does C# support a variable number of arguments?

If yes,  How does C# support variable no of arguments?

What are the examples?

How are variable arguments useful?

**EDIT 1**: What are the restrictions on it?

**EDIT 2**: The Question is not about Optional param But Variable Param

Answer (score 88, accepted):

Yes. The classic example wourld be the `params object[] args`:

```
//Allows to pass in any number and types of parameters
public static void Program(params object[] args)
```

**A typical usecase** would be passing parameters in a command line environment to a program, where you pass them in as strings. The program has then to validate and assign them correctly.

**Restrictions:**

- Only one `params` keyword is permitted per method
- It has to be the last parameter.

EDIT: After I read your edits, I made mine. The part below also covers methods to achieve variable numbers of arguments, but I think you really were looking for the `params` way.

---

Also one of the more classic ones, is called **method overloading**. You've probably used them already a lot:

```
//both methods have the same name and depending on wether you pass in a parameter
//or not, the first or the second is used.
public static void SayHello() {
    Console.WriteLine("Hello");
}
public static void SayHello(string message) {
    Console.WriteLine(message);
}
```

---

Last but not least the most exiting one: **Optional Arguments**

```
//this time we specify a default value for the parameter message
//you now can call both, the method with parameter and the method without.
public static void SayHello(string message = "Hello") {
    Console.WriteLine(message);
}
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264739.aspx

Answer (score 18):

C# supports variable length parameter arrays using the `params` keyword.

Here's an example.

```
public static void UseParams(params int[] list)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < list.Length; i++)
    {
        Console.Write(list[i] + " ");
    }
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

There's more info [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w5zay9db%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

Answer (score 13):

Yes, [params](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w5zay9db.aspx):

```
public void SomeMethod(params object[] args)
```

params has to be the last argument and can be of any type. Not sure if it has to be an array or just an IEnumerable.

Answer (score 11):

I assume you mean a [variable number of method parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w5zay9db%28v=vs.100%29.aspx). If so:

```
void DoSomething(params double[] parms)
```

(Or mixed with fixed parameters)

```
void DoSomething(string param1, int param2, params double[] otherParams)
```

Restrictions:

- They must all be the same type (or of a child type) as is true for arrays as well
- There can only be one for each method
- They must come last in the parameter list

That's all I can think of at the moment though there could be others. Check the documentation for more information.