# Define a function in C# thet get Dynamic parameter?

Tags: c#, winforms

I need to define a function that get some control and do some proccess on them but these control not specified for example these are can be 2 or 4 or 9 or ...
Is any way for define a function that get Dynamic parameter?

Comment: You probably want to use a [*Collection*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ybcx56wz.aspx) of controls, such as `IList<Control>`. Then it's just a matter of obtaining such controls and shoving them into said collection (which depends on where/how the controls are created). In any case, this has nothing to do with "Function Programming".

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9528276/does-c-sharp-support-a-variable-number-of-arguments-and-how

Comment: I've voted to close as a duplicate per the comment "NO I don't want to sent array. I like to send Dynamic parameter like 'String.Format()'".

Comment: here I see some of collusion!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define function like this :

```
public int Test(params object[] r)
        {
           //Your Code
            return 0;
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use params keyword:

```
void Function_Name(params Control[] controls)
{ }
```

Then

```
Function_Name(textBox1);
```

Or

```
Function_Name(textBox1, textBox2);
```

Or

```
Function_Name(textBox1, textBox2, texBox3);
```

Or ...

Answer (score 0):

You may use this as input parameter:

[`params`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w5zay9db.aspx)`object[] input`

for anything, or this:

`params Control[] input`

for `Control` (as user2864740 said).

Comment: NO I don't want to sent array. I like to send Dynamic parameter like 'String.Format()'

Comment: @user3622711: I added the missing `params` that will make it work like `String.Format()`.

Comment: (Make sure to show full relevant syntax, the above is currently hard to follow, especially for someone new to C#. A link to the applicable resource would also help the question.)