# How to pass a dynamic pair of key/values to a function?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, parameter-passing

I've already read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9528276/does-c-sharp-support-a-variable-number-of-arguments-and-how) an [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264739.aspx), but this doesn't answer to my needs.

I'm learning Csharp and here's one of my first functions:

```
public void AskServer(string URL, WWWForm form)
{
    WWWForm form = new WWWForm(URL);
    form.AddField("step", StateManager.STEP_GET_CONF);
    form.AddField("pseudo", this._pseudo);
    form.AddField("jeton", this._dernierJeton.ToString());
    /*... a bit more out of scope code...*/ 
}
```

I would like to do a (far more) generic stuff like this:

```
public void AskServer(string URL, ...)
{
    WWWForm form = new WWWForm(URL);
    /* do a loop on all parameters following the first one */
    for (/*dont know how to write this*/) {
        form.AddField(param[i], param[i+1]);
    )
}
```

then call the function -somehow- like that:

```
AskServer("http://myweb", "pseudo", this._pseudo, "jeton", this._jeton);
```

Maybe if you have a nicer way of writing this, you are welcome, maybe something like in JavaScript:

```
AskServer("http://myweb", {
    "pseudo": this._pseudo,
    "jeton": this._jeton
});
```

One of my problems is that I need to pass value that may not be strings (key will always be).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The params keyword will let you specify a variable number of arguments (must be the last parameter). You can then treat that as an array.

```
public void AskServer(string url, params object[] args)
{
    WWWForm form = new WWWForm(url);

    for (int i = 0; i < args.GetLength(0); i++)
        form.Addfield(args[i].ToString(), args[++i]);
}
```

Called as,

```
AskServer("http://myweb", "pseudo", 1, "jeton", 234);
```

Or as an alternative approach, use a list instead with strong type on the key (the generic declaration is ugly so you can alias it in namespaces)

```
using Kvp = System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair<string, object>;

....

public void AskServer(string url, List<Kvp> kvps)
{
    WWWForm form = new WWWForm(url);

    foreach (var arg in kvps)            
        form.Addfield(arg.Key, arg.Value);            
}
```

Called as:

```
AskServer("http://myweb",
            new List<Kvp>() {
                new Kvp("pseudo", 1),
                new Kvp("jeton", 234)
            });
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed explanation, because I didn't say it, but this was the kind of thing I needed as well: detailed solution.

Answer (score 0):

there are several ways to obtain this result.

parameter array, Tuple, anonymous types, ...

for example you can write

```
public void AskServer(string URL, params object[] values)
{
 ...
}
```

and pass as many parameters as you want

Answer (score 0):

I would try this...

```
public void AskServer(string url, KeyValuePair<string, object>[] parameters)
{
    WWWForm form = new WWWForm(URL);
    /* do a loop on all parameters following the first one */
    for (/*dont know how to write this*/) {
        form.AddField(parameters[i].Key, parameters[i].Value);
    )
}
```