# Minimize code repeatednesses when calling Stored Procedures

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm using a certain method body to call stored procedures, with the following sample code:

```
     public void StoredProcedureThatIsBeingcalled(int variable_1, int variable_2, out DataSet ds)
 {
     using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(DatabaseConnectionString))
     {
         ds = new DataSet("DsToGoOut");
         using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("StoredProcedureThatIsBeingcalled", DbConn.objConn))
         {
             cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;


             cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@variable_1", variable_1));
             cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@variable_2", variable_2));
             try
             {
                 con.Open();
                 SqlDataAdapter objDataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
                 objDataAdapter.SelectCommand = cmd;

                 objDataAdapter.Fill(ds);

                 con.Close();
             }
             catch (Exception ex)
             {

                 //sql_log_err
             }

         }
     }
 }
```

What bugs me I have most of the above code repeating time and time again in my cs file for every different procedure I call.

Obviously I can clear it up and have the one Function being called with the procedure name as a variable, but how do I feed it different number of Parameters (with different Data Types - int,string bool - never anything else) for the different procedures I use ?

I can have few different functions with different number of parameters(0-10), but I feel there is a better way of doing this ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does C# support a variable number of arguments, and how?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9528276/does-c-sharp-support-a-variable-number-of-arguments-and-how)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Update

I know this is a very old question (and in fact, I only stumbled upon it when searching another old answer I gave someone else for closing as duplicate), but I have recently [released a git hub project](https://github.com/Peled-Zohar/ADONETHelper) that answers this very need.
It minimizes code repetition when using ADO.Net by encapsulating the Connection, Command, Parameters, and DataAdapters.
If you want to give it a try I would be glad to know what you think of it.

### First version

You can use a helper class to encapsulate sql parameters and create a single method to handle all dataset fills like this:

Helper class:

```
private class SqlParamDefinition
{

    public SqlParamDefinition(string name, SqlDbType dbType, object value)
    {
        this.Name = name;
        this.DbType = dbType;
        this.Value = value;
    }

    public string Name { get; }
    public SqlDbType DbType { get; }

    public object Value { get; }


}
```

Execute method (based on the method you posted):

```
public DataSet ExecuteSelectProcedure(string procedeureName, params SqlParamDefinition[] parameters)
{
    var ds = new DataSet();
    using (var con = new SqlConnection(DatabaseConnectionString))
    {

        using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(procedeureName, DbConn.objConn))
        {
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            for(int i = 0; i < parameters.Length; i++)
            {
                var param = parameters[i];
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter(param.Name, param.DbType).Value = param.Value);
            }

            try
            {
                con.Open();
                var objDataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
                objDataAdapter.SelectCommand = cmd;

                objDataAdapter.Fill(ds);

                con.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                //sql_log_err
            }

        }
    }
    return ds;
}
```

Calling example:

```
var parameters = new SqlParamDefinition[]
{
    new SqlParamDefinition("@Param1", SqlDbType.VarChar, "value1"),
    new SqlParamDefinition("@Param2", SqlDbType.VarChar, "value2"),
    new SqlParamDefinition("@Param3", SqlDbType.Int, 123),
};

var ds = ExecuteSelectProcedure("Strong procedure name", parameters);
```

Comment: That's pretty much exactly how I imagined it!

Comment: your SqlParamDefinition class looks rather like a copy of SqlParameter

Comment: @Caleth yeah, it's a simplified version of it. It's possible to just use SqlParameter class instead.

Answer (score 4):

I had this issue; I was calling stored procedures on multiple databases.  You could store the stored procedure details e.g. name, input parameters, output parameters etc in database tables and then use a factory method to populate an object (clsStoredProcedure in the example below).  The code would look something like this (I have not tested the code):

```
public void StoredProcedureThatIsBeingcalled(clsStoredProcedure objStoredProcedure)
 {
     using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(objStoredProcedure.ConnectionString))
     {
         ds = new DataSet("DsToGoOut");
         using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(objStoredProcedure.Name, DbConn.objConn))
         {
             cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
foreach (Parameter p in clsStoredProcedure.Parameters)
{
       cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter(p.name, p.value));
}

             try
             {
                 con.Open();
                 SqlDataAdapter objDataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
                 objDataAdapter.SelectCommand = cmd;

                 objDataAdapter.Fill(ds);

                 con.Close();
             }
             catch (Exception ex)
             {

                 //sql_log_err
             }

         }
     }
 }
```

If you are connecting to Oracle databases and SQL Databases then you can use dbConnection, dbCommand etc to connect to the databases.

Answer (score 3):

You can create method that accepts `string` and `Dictionary<string,object>` as parameters. Now you can construct your command according to command text and parameter dictionary. Also, you can extend this method and use it for select, insert etc. queries.

Example:

```
private void ExecCommand(string commandText, Dictionary<string, object> param)
{
 using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(DatabaseConnectionString))
 {
     ds = new DataSet("DsToGoOut");
     using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(commandText, DbConn.objConn))
     {
         cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

         //***************************************
         // New method
         cmd = AddParametersToCommand(cmd, param);
         //***************************************

         try
         {
             con.Open();
             SqlDataAdapter objDataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
             objDataAdapter.SelectCommand = cmd;

             objDataAdapter.Fill(ds);

             con.Close();
         }
         catch (Exception ex)
         {

             //sql_log_err
         }

     }
 }
}
```

And `AddParametersToCommand`:

```
private SQLCommand AddParametersToCommand(SqlCommand command, Dictionary<string, object> parameters)
{
    if (parameters == null || command == null)
    {
        return;
    }


    SQLCommand tempCommand = command;

    foreach (var param in parameters)
    {
        var parameter = tempCommand.CreateParameter();
        parameter.ParameterName = param.Key;
        parameter.Value = param.Value ?? DBNull.Value;
        tempCommand.Parameters.Add(parameter);
    }

    return tempCommand;
}
```

And use it like:

```
Dictionary<string, object> parameters = new Dictionary<string, object>();
parameters.Add("@variable_1", variable_1);
parameters.Add("@variable_2", variable_2);

ExecCommand("StoredProcedureThatIsBeingcalled", parameters);
```

Comment: The drawback to this approach is that you end up guessing parameter types or just making them all `nvarchar(max)` or similar, which can result in decidedly suboptimal execution plans.

Answer (score 2):

So,

You can use dapper to execute stored procedures. https://github.com/StackExchange/dapper-dot-net

You can declare a DTO model that will be mapped using what you selected in your stored procedure.

```
public class DogDto
{
    public int? Age { get; set; }
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public float? Weight { get; set; }

    public int IgnoredProperty { get { return 1; } }
}   

// _databaseConnectionString is your database connection string
using (var conn = new SqlConnection(_databaseConnectionString)){
var dog = cnn.Query<DogDto>("schema.spGetDog", new {Id = 120}, 
        commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure).SingleOrDefault();
 }

// and let's assume we have schema.spGetDog stored procedure already declared in our database 
// and be aware that the 2nd parameter after the stored procedure name are the stored procedure parameters
```

Your stored procedure must select columns Age, Id, Name, Weight (mapping being realized by property name). I don't really know if you can change this comportment, because if you have the same columns/properties in database / dto's that are using stored procedures the development process will be faster.

And just for the record, as per documentation: *"Dapper has no DB specific implementation details, it works across all .NET ADO providers including SQLite, SQL CE, Firebird, Oracle, MySQL, PostgreSQL and SQL Server."*

And this is all you need to do.