# How to implement a generic retry pattern for methods with parameters

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.8, retry-logic

So far I implemented this:

```csharp
public class Retrier
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Execute a method with no parameters multiple times with an interval
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="TResult"></typeparam>
    /// <param name="function"></param>
    /// <param name="tryTimes"></param>
    /// <param name="interval"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static TResult Execute<TResult>(Func<TResult> function, int tryTimes, int interval)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < tryTimes - 1; i++)
        {
            try
            {
                return function();
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(interval);
            }
        }

        return function();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Execute a method with 1 parameter multiple times with an interval
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T"></typeparam>
    /// <typeparam name="TResult"></typeparam>
    /// <param name="function"></param>
    /// <param name="arg1"></param>
    /// <param name="tryTimes"></param>
    /// <param name="interval"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static TResult Execute<T, TResult>(Func<T, TResult> function, T arg1, int tryTimes, int interval)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < tryTimes - 1; i++)
        {
            try
            {
                return function(arg1);
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(interval);
            }
        }

        return function(arg1);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Execute a method with 2 parameters multiple times with an interval
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T1"></typeparam>
    /// <typeparam name="T2"></typeparam>
    /// <typeparam name="TResult"></typeparam>
    /// <param name="function"></param>
    /// <param name="arg1"></param>
    /// <param name="arg2"></param>
    /// <param name="tryTimes"></param>
    /// <param name="interval"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static TResult Execute<T1, T2, TResult>(Func<T1, T2, TResult> function, T1 arg1, T2 arg2, int tryTimes, int interval)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < tryTimes - 1; i++)
        {
            try
            {
                return function(arg1, arg2);
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(interval);
            }
        }

        return function(arg1, arg2);
    }
}
```

The problem is that it becomes difficult to maintain.
When I have a method with more variables, I need to implement another `Execute` method.
In case I need to change anything I have to change it in all methods.

So I wonder if there is a clean way to make it one method that will handle any number of parameters?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does C# support a variable number of arguments, and how?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9528276/does-c-sharp-support-a-variable-number-of-arguments-and-how)

Comment: Isn't that reinventing the wheel, when we have [Polly](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly)?

Comment: @HereticMonkey, Thanks, but it's not really the same.
When I pass the function, I need to pass the types of parameters as well.
Which means, if I pass the parameters as `params`, the function will "not know" that it should get parameters...

Comment: Thanks @Fildor, if don't find an easy solution I will probably use it. I still think it doesn't worth importing a whole package for this simple task.

Comment: Since the retry logic simply forwards the arguments, why not stick to a single method that just takes a `Func<TResult>`? Consumers will just pass a closure in which all the arguments are filled in. The function's arguments are opaque to the retry method in all of your examples anyway.

Comment: You can already handle arbitrary parameters using partial application

Comment: You only need the multi-parameter overloads for performance reasons, to avoid allocating a new delegate on each call.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you said your current design does not support n and n+1 parameters without code change.

Here are two common practices that can come to rescue.

#### Define variants upfront

If you look at the [`Action`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.action-1?view=net-7.0) and [`Func`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.func-1?view=net-7.0) delegates then you can see there are multiple variants from no parameter till 16 parameters.

[image: Action variants]

You can follow the same concept in case of `Execute`. The beauty here is that you can generate this code via [T4](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/modeling/code-generation-and-t4-text-templates?view=vs-2022).

#### Anticipate anonymous functions

Rather than having handful of overloads you can cover all cases with this

```
public static TResult Execute<TResult>(Func<TResult> function, int tryTimes, int interval)
```

and all asynchronous cases with that:

```
public static Task<TResult> ExecuteAsync<TResult>(Func<Task<TResult>> function, int tryTimes, int interval)
```

The trick here is that how you pass the parameters

```
Execute(MyFunction);
Execute(() => MyFunction()); //This is exactly the same as the above one
Execute(() => MyOtherFunction(param1));
```

```
ExecuteAsync(MyFunctionAsync);
ExecuteAsync(() => MyFunctionAsync()); //This works if `ExecuteAsync` awaits `function` 
ExecuteAsync(async () => await MyOtherFunctionAsync(param1));
```

So, with the following four methods you can cover all methods and functions regardless they are synchronous or asynchronous

```
void Execute(Action method, int tryTimes, int interval)
TResult Execute<TResult>(Func<TResult> function, int tryTimes, int interval)
Task ExecuteAsync<TResult>(Func<Task> asyncMethod, int tryTimes, int interval)
Task<TResult> ExecuteAsync<TResult>(Func<Task<TResult>> asyncFunction, int tryTimes, int interval)
```

Answer (score 2):

I made a nuget package called [Mulligan](https://github.com/maxinfet/Mulligan) for accomplishing this; if you don't want to use my package, you could at least see an example of doing retries. I created this package after wanting to use the [retry code](https://github.com/TestStack/White/blob/master/src/TestStack.White/Utility/Retry.cs) found in [TestStack.White](https://github.com/TestStack/White) outside that library without copying and pasting it each time. The core functionality in Mulligan can be found in [Retry.cs](https://github.com/maxinfet/Mulligan/blob/master/Mulligan/Retry.cs).

You could also look at how [Polly](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly) implements their retry logic if you really need to reimplement it yourself and it is not .NET code, but this [library](https://github.com/resilient-http/resilient.js/) is a thorough implementation as well. Whenever I get the time, I plan to look at these libraries and port as much as I can to mulligan, so you might find this a useful source of inspiration.

Hopefully, seeing all these side-by-side gives you some good examples to work off of, as well as the progression between implementations at different maturity levels.

Answer (score 2):

To be truly generic, your function would have to have all sorts of prototypes to handle different numbers of arguments, out, ref, async, etc. What a pain! Fortunately it doesn't have to handle the arguments at all. Instead of wrapping a function, wrap the *invocation* of that function, including assignment of parameters.

```
public static void Execute(Action action, int tryTimes, int interval)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < tryTimes - 1; i++)
    {
        try
        {
            action();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(interval);
        }
    }

    action();
}
```

Then you just invoke it like this:

```
Execute( () => {
    Foo();  //Don't pass any arguments or read any result
}, 1, 2000);
```

Or

```
Execute( () => {
    var x = Foo(2);  //One numeric input and read the return value
}, 3, 1000);
```

Or

```
Execute( () => {
    Foo("Hello", out var x);  //Use one string argument and read the out parameter
}, 5, 2000);
```

If you want to handle async too, add one more prototype so the caller can access the task (and so you can use `Task.Delay` instead of `Sleep`):

```
public static async Task Execute(Func<Task> action, int tryTimes, int interval)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < tryTimes - 1; i++)
    {
        try
        {
            return await action();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            await Task.Delay(interval);
        }
    }

    return await action();
}
```

and use like this:

```
await Execute( async () => {
    var x = await Foo();
}, 5, 2000);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can already handle arbitrary parameters using partial application.

```
Retrier.Execute(()=>OtherFunc(1,"banana",DateTime.Now),tryTimes:3,interval:5000);
```

This is a common technique in functional programming *and* LINQ - a `Where` operation expects a `Func<T,bool>` which usually involves variables and members outside the `T` type, eg :

```
var cutoff=DateTime.Today.AddDays(-5);

var newUsers=users.Where(user=>user.Created>cutoff);
```

This allocates a new delegate each time it's called, which is why some libraries have overloads for multiple parameters, purely for performance reasons.

Answer (score 1):

So taking into account the answers so far, and my requirements from this task I solved this by implementing 2 methods (One for methods that return a value (`Func`) and one for methods that do not return a value (`Action`).

```csharp
public class Retrier
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Execute a method with a generic return value
    /// Try multiple times with an interval
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="TResult"></typeparam>
    /// <param name="function"></param>
    /// <param name="tryTimes"></param>
    /// <param name="interval"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static TResult Execute<TResult>(Func<TResult> function, int tryTimes, int interval)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < tryTimes - 1; i++)
        {
            try
            {
                return function();
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(interval);
            }
        }

        return function();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Execute a method that does not return a value
    /// Try multiple times with an interval
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="action"></param>
    /// <param name="tryTimes"></param>
    /// <param name="interval"></param>
    public static void Execute(Action action, int tryTimes, int interval)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < tryTimes - 1; i++)
        {
            try
            {
                action();
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(interval);
            }
        }

        action();
    }
}
```

Now, when I need it to return a value, I can call it this way:

```csharp
var result = Retrier.Execute(() =>
{
    return _client.GetSomthing(param1, param2, param3);
}, _maxCallTries, _callRetriesIntervalMilliseconds);
```

And when I need it to run somthing, I can use this:

```csharp
Retrier.Execute(() =>
{
    _client.DoSomthing(param1, param2, param3);
}, _maxCallTries, _callRetriesIntervalMilliseconds);
```